# PHP exec: hangs, doesn't continue to next line

Tags: php, terminal, exec, shell-exec

I have a php file 'run.php' which I'm running from the terminal. Within this file I have the following lines:

exec("open-crawlers $port 2>&1",$out,$code);
   echo 'hello';

The problem that I'm having is that the terminal hangs after executing the 'exec' command; the program doesn't reach the second line.

Comment: What happens when you execute it on the command line yourself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec("nohup open-crawlers $port >> /tmp/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
echo 'hello';
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer inspired my solution,this command worked for me:

exec("open-crawlers $port >> error.txt 2>&1 &",$out,$code);

Comment: Just a comment in case someone else has the problem I did. You have to both pipe the output to a file as well as the appended "&". If you don't pipe the output, it will hang. Just pipe to /dev/null if you don't care about it.

Comment: Love you : ) : )

Answer (score 0):

If you are here using StormPHP and xdebug:

Raise your "settings/debugger/max simulatanious connections"

e.g.: from 3 to 5